# Creating a font with blackboard characters for as many engines as possible?

Tags: fonts, blackboard

For some texts that I am typesetting, I would like to have more blackboard letters than are usually available with the AMS fonts (or with fourierbb etc.)

In particular, I felt the need to denote the function that only assumes 0 as a blackboard 0, but *not* with, say, `$\mathbb{O}$` (that's a capital letter o, not a zero), and a blackboard 1 for the function that only assumes 1 (this is particularly useful when one is talking about arithmetic functions and the Möbius inversion formula).

For typesetting with plain latex, I have used `MinionPro` with `MnSymbols` and looking a little bit, I found the package `bbold` to be *almost* what I wanted, but with two exceptions:

1. The fonts embedded in the final PDF document are Type 3 fonts.
2. They don't actually match the look of `MinionPro`.

Looking a bit further, I saw that the [DejaVu](http://dejavu-fonts.org/) fonts produced by the DejaVu project has all symbols in the set `[A-Za-z0-1]` in a very free license, they actually look reasonable with `MinionPro` (and Linux Libertine) and, with the source format in Fontforge, I was able to strip all the characters to create a PostScript Type 1 font.

But here is my problem: After I did all that, I am using the [following python script](https://gist.github.com/rbrito/1306378) to create the `pfb` file, but I had no success using the fonts after installation, but I *did* have success if I used directly

```
$\font\blackboardfont=fdjr8r at 10pt$
```

instead of what I would understand as being the "normal" way:

```
$\font\blackboardfont=fdj at 10pt$
```

that is, without the type and encoding hardcoded.

This must be a really elementary question, but I am lacking some background here and I would appreciate if others could help me learn what I am doing incorrectly so that I can also offer this on CTAN, as I saw that looking for blackboard letters and numbers is more popular than what I thought at first.

If it helps, I can upload the whole stuff that I have here to github.

Comment: There is a Type1 version of BBold on CTAN/TeXlive for a while now. STIX and ESSTIX fonts have good blackboard coverage as well, you may want to check that (the later are available on CTAN with TeX support.)

Comment: @KhaledHosny, oh, great to know about the BBold Type1 version. I will try it again.OTOH, its look didn't quite match the look of MinionPro or Linux Libertine, which is why I took the blackboard characters from DejaVu Sans, but, given the script that I pointed, I may be doing something incorrectly. Do you see anything obviously wrong? Oh, on thing: I want "regular" fonts for TeX for collaboration purposes with people with old installations. But I would like more to *learn*, of course. :)

Comment: I think you are mixing TeX and LaTeX-methods to call fonts. With the primitive `\font` command you must use "full" names like `fdjr8r`. To call a font throught its family name "fdj" e.g. with the LaTeX commands (\fontfamily{fdj} etc) you need some additional macro level like the LaTeX nfss with fd-files.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. Yes, that was one problem inded: the lack of a fd file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [`mbboard` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mbboard)? It contains an obscene amount of "blackboard" symbols.

Note that the package is *not* included neither in MiKTeX 2.9 nor TeXLive 2011, but it's easy enough to install in your local `texmf` directory.

The symbols you're looking for can easily be typeset so:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mbboard}

\begin{document}
  The $\mathbb{0}$ symbol is used to denote a function that only assumes 0,
  whilst the  $\mathbb{1}$ symbol is used to denote a function that only
  assumes 1.
\end{document}
```

Hope it helps!

PS: does anyone know *why* it's not included in either distribution? licensing issues?

Comment: Thanks @mpr. I also wonder why it is not included in the main distributions. I just skimmed the description of the fonts and it seems that the only potential problem with the fonts would be their (again, potential) "non-freeness".